# Print hidden iframe using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery to create an iFrame in a page.  I am then appending content to the iFrame and I want to print the contents of that iFrame using jQuery.  I am using the code below, but it just tries to print a blank page.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$("#projects").on("click", ".print-row", function() {
        var theForm = $(this).closest('form');
        var rowParent = $(this).closest('tr');
        var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');

        $.post("printProject.php", {id: id}, function(data)
        {
            var data = $.parseJSON(data);
            var table = data[0];
            var type = data.type;

            if(type) {
                $("div#messages").html('<div class="' + type + '-message">Your document will start printing shortly...</div>').slideDown("slow");
            }

            try {
                var $iframe = $('<iframe id="iframePrint">').appendTo('body');
                $iframe.ready(function() {
                    $iframe.contents().find("body").append(table);
                });
                alert($("#iframePrint").get(0));
                $("#iframePrint").get(0).contentWindow.print();
            } 
            catch(e) {
                self.print();
            }
        });

        return false;
});
```

Comment: Are you using any `print` css? Try google on how to set it up

Comment: `$iframe.ready(function() {` <-- asynchronous

Comment: @charlietfl no, not using print css

Comment: @epascarello - not sure what that means..what do I need to change?

Comment: We are not using any     print css.